# Result of `document.getElementsByClassName` doesn't have array methods like `map` defined, even though it is an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have the following bit of code to select some divs and add a click handler on them

```
var tiles = document.getElementsByClassName("tile");

tiles.map(function(tile, i){
    tile.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        console.log("click!");
    });
});
```

This throws an error because `map` is not defined, even though tiles is an array.
If I make an array like this, then map works fine:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
a.map(/*whatever*/);
```

A workaround is to attach map to tiles like this:

```
tiles.map = Array.prototype.map;
```

This works fine. 
My question is why doesn't `tiles` have map defined on it? Is it not really an array?

Comment: It's not an array - it's NodeList. Still, you can use it as is with a little context-swapping magic: `[].map.call(tiles)`. Note, though, that in this specific case you should use `.forEach` instead - as you don't use the result of `.map`.

Comment: ah you're right. I'll use `forEach` instead

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Right, it's not really an array. It's an "array-like".

Don't attach `map` to `tiles`. Just do

```
Array.prototype.map.call(tiles, function...)
```

Some might suggest

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(tiles).map(function...
```

which sort of boils down to the same thing. There are those who prefer to write

```
[].slice.call(tiles).map(function...
```

which saves a few keystrokes.

Of course, since you're not really using `map` to return an array, you could loop in the old-fashioned way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
    tiles[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        console.log("click!");
    });
}
```

See also [explanation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Why_can't_I_use_forEach_or_map_on_a_NodeList.3F). Although this discusses `NodeList`, the same principles apply to `HTMLCollection`, which is what `getElementsByClassName` returns.

In ES6, we have some easier ways to turn `tiles` into an array, including

```
[...tiles]
Array.from(tiles)
```

Comment: Possibly clearer to use `forEach` to capture the specific file and avoid later problems of reading `tiles[i]` with the wrong `i`. Also it's specifically an `HTMLCollection` that is returned.

Comment: what problems does `tiles.map = Array.prototype.map;` cause?

Comment: Nothing fatal, but you don't want to need to be doing that every time you call `getElementsbyClassName`. You could in theory add it to the HTMLCollection prototype, as in `HTMLCollection.prototype.map = Array.prototype.map`, but that kind of thing is usually frowned on.