# can't get index of current clicked element in array using javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my HTML code

```js
var link = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
for (i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
  link[i].addEventListener("click", click);

  function click() {
    console.log(link.indexOf(this));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="hole-counter"><span></span></div><a class="link">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hole-counter"><span></span></div><a class="link">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hole-counter"><span></span></div><a class="link">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="hole-counter"><span></span></div><a class="link">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And this is javascript code

i get this error in console
Uncaught TypeError: link.indexOf is not a function at HTMLAnchorElement.click (index.html:97)

Comment: HTMLCollections are not arrays. you have to convert them to arrays first before you can use array methods on them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Result of \`document.getElementsByClassName\` doesn't have array methods like \`map\` defined, even though it is an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409397/result-of-document-getelementsbyclassname-doesnt-have-array-methods-like-map)

Comment: es6 = `var link = [...document.getElementsByClassName('link')]` or just use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: thanks, it worked now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link variable is not an Array, therefore you cannot call indexOf() on it. You must first convert link to an array. 
`var link = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("link"));`

Answer (score 2):

The link variable in your code is HTMLCollection, you need to convert it to an array before using `indexOf`

You can do this

```
const links = [...document.getElementsByClassName("link")];
links.forEach(link => link.addEventListener("click", click));

function click() {
  console.log(links.indexOf(this))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The link variable is an array like element, you need to convert that to an array first:

```
var link = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
for (i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
    link[i].addEventListener("click", click);
}

function click() {
    console.log(Array.from(link).indexOf(this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link variable is just a variable and the indexOf function is specifically for arrays. So you should first convert your variable into an array. You can do that by either declaring it as an array or converting it into an array afterwards.